# DIV losing focus when clicking on elements inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the DIV lose focus when i click on elements inside it?
I have an JS that hides the DIV when it loses focus. But that should not happen when clicking on elements inside the DIV.
It needs to be done with .on because there is some ajax loading going on.

```
$(document).on('focusout', '#geomodal', function(e) {
    console.log('.focusout');
});
```

```html
<div id="geomodal" tabindex="-1">
    <input value="109" name="districts[]" type="checkbox">
    <label>Bla</label>
    <br>
    <input value="152673" name="districts[]" type="checkbox">
    <label>Blabla</label>
    <br>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2g41su81/2/

jQuery Documentation:

> The focusout event is sent to an element when it, or any element
>   inside of it,  loses focus.

Comment: This behaviour is correct, `#geomodal` is losing focus as focus is being given to a child element. What behaviour are you trying to achieve?

Comment: yeah but how can the div keep focus when clicking on elements inside it?

Comment: **Form elements** steal the focus when clicking on them. Normal child elements without tabindex don't.

Comment: @Mike you can't - the act of clicking on another element changes the focus.

Comment: Only one element has focus at a time - if an input has focus, your div doesn't. Can you change your hide function to test if the newly-focused element is inside your div, and not hide in that case?

Comment: @Mike which ajax call ?? can you please explain , share the code

Comment: @anam that would be too much not problem specific code i think. The "geomodal"  html is just loaded via ajax into the page.

Comment: What do you want to do on focusout? If we know that we could propose an alternative since this way it won't work.

Comment: if( $(this).find("input").is(":focus") )  ... this if-condition inside #geomodal on.function will return true if any of its input has focus

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Spokey "I have an JS that hides the DIV when it loses focus. But that should not happen when clicking on elements inside the DIV."

Comment: I think they meant normal elements and not form elements, if you were to look at the [example on the jQuery page for focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/#entry-examples) you'll notice it doesn't work with inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one element has focus at a time - if an input has focus, your div doesn't. After losing focus, check if the newly-focused element is your div or a child, and don't hide it in that case.

```
$(document).on('focusout', '#geomodal', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var focus=$(document.activeElement);
        if (focus.is("#geomodal") || $('#geomodal').has(focus).length) {
            console.log("still focused");
        } else {
            console.log(".focusout");
        }
    },0);
});
```

The `setTimeout` is necessary to allow the new element to gain focus before doing the check.

http://jsfiddle.net/2g41su81/5/

Comment: That's it my friend. The has() selector is great!

Answer (score 3):

you can also use `e.relatedTarget` to get the element which caused the *focusout* to be triggered and do handling according to that!

Answer (score 2):

check this example.

the focusout event is not execute while click on inner elements

Check the "tabindex" attribute, is the trick

Html Code

```
<div id="mydiv" tabindex="100">
    <div class="anotherdiv">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" value=1>
    </div>
    <div class="anotherdiv"> child content
        <input type="checkbox" name="" value=1>
    </div>  
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tierrarara/kPbfL/425/

JS Code

```
$("#mydiv").focusin(function() {
    $("#mydiv").css("background","red");
});
$("#mydiv").focusout(function() {
    $("#mydiv").css("background","white");
});
```

CSS Code

```
#mydiv{
    width : 50px;
    height:auto;
    border : 1px solid red;
}

.anotherdiv{
    width : 50px;
    height:50px;
    border : 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Perfect Solution-> It works when we use tabindex..  thanks for the trick..