# .class with display: none -> .class:focus with display: block; causes links to not work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an options menu of sorts. When the user clicks a box, an inner box will appear within the first with a link. Note: This inner (second) box is critical. Clicking away from this first box or clicking another box will hide the first box's inner box.

The link within the second box doesn't work open the webpage (even with target set to _blank) and instead it hides the inner box.

I've only been able to get the show/hide toggle inner box functionality by using :focus with display: none -> display: block

Isolated example: https://codepen.io/Rogue75/pen/ewdQZq

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="box" tabindex="1">
        <p>Click anywhere in this box.</p>    
        <div class="inner_box">
            <p>Click this <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">link</a>.</p>
        </div>      
    </div> 
    <!-- REPEATS THE ABOVE TWICE -->
    <div class="box" tabindex="2">
        <p>Click anywhere in this box.</p>    
        <div class="inner_box">
            <p>Click this <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">link</a>.</p>
        </div>      
    </div>    
    <div class="box" tabindex="3">
        <p>Click anywhere in this box.</p>    
        <div class="inner_box">
            <p>Click this <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">link</a>.</p>
        </div>      
    </div>    
    <!-- NO HIDE BELOW -->    
    <div class="nohide_box" tabindex="3">
        <p><B>This box doesn't show/hide anything.</p>
        <div class="nohide_inner_box">
            <p>Click this <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">link</a> which works.</p>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

```
.container {

}

.box, .nohide_box {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  background-color: pink;
}

.inner_box {
  display: none;
  background-color: wheat;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.box:focus .inner_box {
  display: block;
}

.nohide_box {
  background-color: lightgreen !important;
}
```

The link should work, and ideally the inner box would stay put, but instead the link doesn't work and the inner box hides. My goal is to:

- Have these boxes (div) show an inner box (div) when clicked on
- When clicking away or on another box having the inner box hide
- Have a functional link exist inside of the inner box (div) which keeps the inner box visible after it's clicked.

Ideally this would be all done with only HTML & CSS, but at this point I'm open to some low-taxing scripts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28214476/2427237

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this works for your usecase, but you can "trick" it by changing the CSS to the following:

```
.box:focus .inner_box,
.box:focus-within .inner_box,
.inner_box:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

so the box doesn't close as long as you're mouse is still hovering the div.

*Updated as per OP comment:* consider using `:focus-within` along with `:focus`to keep the Div visible as long as some child-element has focus (doesn't work in Edge 
 yet https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-focus-within)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It works in the codepen example, but not in my actual deployment. I'll keep tinkering with it and will get back to you.

Comment: Looks like the trick involved using .box:focus, .box:focus-within on the same display: block styling. Now an object focused within it would trigger the same event!! Thanks for you leading me into the fix. Please update your answer, and I will mark it as correct.