# div loses focus, when clicked on a child which has focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus

So, I am making a modal which has focus on it when it is shown.
And if the user clicks outside, I want to hide it.
I have implemented this with the help of focus events.

In cases, where the modal itself has a child which is focusable, modal loses the focus, I have also handled it in the below code. These cases are correctly handled by `onFocusLoss` but not by `onFocusLoss2`.

```js
function onClickButton() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
  modal.style.visibility = 'visible';
  modal.focus();
}

function onFocusLoss() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    var activeEl = document.activeElement;
    
    if (modal !== activeEl && !modal.contains(activeEl)) {
      modal.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
  }, 0);
}

function onFocusLoss2() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
  var activeEl = document.activeElement;
  
  if (modal !== activeEl && !modal.contains(activeEl)) {
    modal.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}
```

```css
#modal {
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#modal > div {
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='onClickButton()'>Show Modal</button>
<div id='modal' tabindex='-1' onfocusout='onFocusLoss()'>
  <div>Focus Test</div>
  <div>
    <input>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how I assume focus events are going, when the modal is focused and then I click inside input,
then first the modal loses focus, the body is the active element, and then the input element becomes the active element, and body loses focus.

Thus, the reason maybe that `onFocusLoss2` is not handling the case because `activeEl` at that time is the body, while in `onFocusLoss`, the `activeEl` is the input.

My question is, why one approach is working and the other is not? I want a *good* technical reason. If your answer is that it gives enough time so that input element gains focus, I want to know how can you say that the time is enough and will always work?

My solution is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28214476/8455110), though.

Answer (score 0):

May wish to change your mind. When the modal is focused, add a click event to the element below it to close the modal.

```html
<body>
  <button onclick='onClickButton()'>Show Modal</button>
  <div id='modal' tabindex='-1'>
    <div>Focus Test</div>
    <div>
      <input>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```js
function onClickButton() {
  const modal = document.getElementById('modal');
  modal.style.visibility = 'visible';
  modal.focus();
  document.body.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    modal.style.visiable = 'hidden'
  })
}
```

Don't forget to adjust modal's `z-index` to make sure it's above the body.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @RiverTwilight, I'm removing the focus need and simply adding an onClick event.

I placed a `<div>` inside your `#modal` and made `#modal` fill the whole screen, this way you can use different animations and other techniques to also animate your content as long as `#modal` doesn't have padding.

I hope you get your answer. ✌️

```js
function onClickButton() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
  modal.style.visibility = 'visible';
  modal.focus();
}

function onModalBGClick(e) {
  var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
  var activeEl = e.target;
  
  if (activeEl === modal) {
    modal.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}
```

```css
#modal {
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.modal-inner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#modal > div {
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='onClickButton()'>Show Modal</button>
<div id='modal' onclick='onModalBGClick(event)'>
  <div class="modal-inner">
    <div>Focus Test</div>
    <div>
      <input>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```